gdb version not the same with gcc and g++
after I setup MSYS2 and install complete I have checked version of gcc and g++ they were same version but gdb is not same it newer than gcc and g++. Could you please help on that?
All three those should be same version. Thanks

Why would gdb version number be the same of gcc ? Those are two different software

Mine are also different, it's never caused any problems for me. Where are you getting your information?

VTC: why would you expect the gcc and gdb versions to be the same? If you have your reasons, it should be discussed with the authors. In the packeg index they are different.

"All three those should be same version." No they shouldn't, they are numbered independently.

Thanks all for help, the first time sorry for my thoughtless question. I am newbie, and I want to learn and verify for my thought because after I checked I saw that and I don't understand what is gcc, g++ and gdb? What funtions of them? so Thanks for your help

You know they exist but don't know what they are? gcc = C compiler, g++ = C++ compiler, gdb = debugger.

The versioning policies for GDB and GCC are described here:



Software
Versioning Policy




GCC
https://gcc.gnu.org/develop.html


GDB
https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/



They have different versioning policies, so it is also the case possible that GDB has now version 14.x whilst GCC has still 13.7. So, everything is fine, and the software could be just used with keeping in mind the known problems described in the errata.
